# How to save the content of global variable to a lexical variables in Perl and access it from sub

Tags: perl

I'm trying to save the content of a `our` global variable declared in the main script, to a `my` lexical variable in a module.

**main.pl**

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use module;

our $global = "Hello";

function();
```

**module.pm**

```
package module;

use strict;
use warnings;

use Exporter 'import';
our @EXPORT = qw(  function );


# some needed initialization & definition before subs 
my $var = $main::global;


sub function {

print $var,"\n"; 

}

1;
```

I'm facing : Use of uninitialized value $var error

Even when i try to do a print just under the assignment, it doesn't work !
Thanks.

Comment: Compiling `use module;` loads the module --which is to say executes the module-- before the compiler goes any further. In short, you are executing `my $var = $main::global;` before `our $global = "Hello";`.

Comment: It makes no sense for a module to reach into its user's namespace like that. What are you trying to do??

Comment: Indeed, why do you want that?  One _can_ pass to the module's `import` (which you'd have to write yourself then), in the`use` statement -- but that's almost certainly a bad idea and there's a better way to do whatever it is you actually need.

Comment: i'm trying to access a one time declared variable (in main.pl) from different external modules, do you think it's possible, or should i rethink my philosophy.

Comment: If you put the `my $var = ...` line inside of `sub function` your code will otherwise work like you expect. But doing stuff like this leads to very confusing and hard-to-read code (I know from experience). It's better to pass as an argument, like `function($global);`, or perhaps consider using an object-oriented approach where you pass it to the module's constructor (see `perldoc perlootut` for an intro to OO style Perl)

Answer (score 1):

finally i got what i want by creating a module which contain all the global variable i want. and use it everywhere when needed.

it look like this

```
package Globals;

use Exporter 'import';
our @EXPORT = qw( $VERSION $DEV_EMAIL $BASEDIR $CURRENT_PROJECT );

our $VERSION = "0.0.1";
our $DEV_EMAIL = "FOO@BAR.COM";
our $BASEDIR = "./Projects/";
our $CURRENT_PROJECT = '';

1;
```

OtherPackage.pm

```
package OtherPackage
use Globals;

my $var = $VERSION

# do something with $var
print $var;

1;
```

Comment: Good job, that's an incomparably better way to do it (than what was asked for).  Note though that exporting variables (as opposed to functions) is considered iffy, to say the least (at leaest consider importing those constants under `@EXPORT_OK` so that they have to be explicitly asked for).  In the end, writing a class would be better yet.